# Pass opt arguments in an application executed as a .jar through spark-submit --class and use the existing context

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am writting a scala project that I want to have classes that are executable from spark-submit as a jar class. (e.g. `spark-submit --class org.project`

My problems are the following:

1. I want to use the spark-context-configuration that the user sets when doing a spark submit and overwrite optionally some parameters like the Application name. Example: `spark-submit --num-executors 6 --class org.project` will pass 6 in number of exectors configuration field in spark context.
2. I want to be able to pass option parameters like `--inputFile` or `--verbose` to my project without interfering with the spark parameters (possibly with avoid name overlap)
   Example: `spark-submit --num-executors 6 --class org.project --inputFile ./data/mystery.txt` should pass `"--inputFile ./data/mystery.txt"` to the args input of class `org.project` `main` method.

What my progress is in those problems is the following:

1. I run `val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("project");
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf);`
   in my `main` method,
   but I am not sure if this does things as expected.
2. Sparks considers those optional arguments as arguments of the spark-submit and outputs an error.

Note.1: My java class `project` currently does not inherit any other class.

Note.2: I am new to the world of spark and I couldn't find something relative from a basic search.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle parameter parsing yourself.  Here we use `Scopt`.

When your spark-submit your job, it must enter through an object `def main(args: Array[String])`.  Takes theses args and parse them using your favorite argument parser, set your sparkConf and SparkSession accordingly and launch your process.

Spark has examples of that whole idea:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/DenseKMeans.scala